# Transition viewcontrollers from anywhere in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification, uistoryboardsegue

I have a timer in my app.  I have local notifications for the the 30, 10 and 5 second marks.  All of my view controllers come from a main view controller.  The view that I want to transition to when the notifications are touched/slid obviously comes from that same main view as well.  Like this:

MainView --> AnyView in the app
    |
    |
    V
Timer view

I am using storyboards.  And the client does not have time for me to rework everything all over again.

I want the user to be able to touch a back button from the timer view, after they have entered that view.

I have the Local Notification setup so that I post a notification throughout the app that I have most of my view controllers listening to, so I just need to figure out what to do in the method that gets called from the current view controller.  I am thinking I can popToRoot, from the navigation controller, and then performSegueWithIdentifier to the timer view controller.  I know how to do the first popToRoot part, but the performSegueWithIdentifier is where I am stuck.

I want to popToRoot, then perform segue, from a pushed ViewController.

I probably can't do that directly from the following method though.  What would be best?  Send another notification that only calls a method in my main view controller that does the perform segue?

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(timerLocalNotification)
                                             name:TIMER_LOCAL_NOTIFICATION
                                           object:nil];
 }

 -(void)timerLocalNotification
 {
     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

     // I want to perform a segue from RootViewcontroller.
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't just want to pop the top view controller? It isn't easy to follow your question...

Comment: Sorry, I want to pop to the main screen, there could be multiple pushed view controllers.  Then once at the main screen, I want to performSegue.

Comment: That is all the code...  Does that even help?

Comment: Can you handle the notification on the root view instead of the top view?

Comment: Yes, I can.  Can I pop from a previous viewcontroller?

Comment: The view controller doesn't matter to the pop, so long as you can get a reference to the navigation controller.